# MongoDB Fluent Aggregate Conditional Stages

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregate, mongodb-.net-driver, fluent

When using the Fluent aggregation interface, why doesn't the stages added later not work (stage 3)?

```
var fluentPipeline = _userToGroup.Aggregate()
            .AppendStage<BsonDocument>("stage 1")
            .AppendStage<BsonDocument>("stage 2");
if (condition)
    fluentPipeline.AppendStage<BsonDocument>("stage 3");
fluentPipeline.ToListAsync();
```

Stage 3 works when added to the pipeline in the same code line like below. Which means it is not a problem with the stage but how the stage is added to the pipeline as I understand it. The question is why?

```
var fluentPipeline = _userToGroup.Aggregate()
            .AppendStage<BsonDocument>("stage 1")
            .AppendStage<BsonDocument>("stage 2")
            .AppendStage<BsonDocument>("stage 3");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open [github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/2568c34500ed88e8944ea6555b1c411bce803f06/src/MongoDB.Driver/PipelineDefinitionBuilder.cs) to preview the body of the `AppendStage` method.

It turns out that there's a `return` statement so it always returns a new `PipelineDefinition` instead of modifying the existing one. Therefore you have to assign this returned value to a variable. Try:

```
var fluentPipeline = _userToGroup.Aggregate()
            .AppendStage<BsonDocument>("stage 1")
            .AppendStage<BsonDocument>("stage 2");

if (condition)
    fluentPipeline = fluentPipeline.AppendStage<BsonDocument>("stage 3");

fluentPipeline.ToListAsync();
```