# How to check only top 1 in nested mongo array

Tags: c#, mongodb

at the moment my notification documents has an events property which is an array of event. Each event has a status and a date. When querying notifications, it needs to check if the top status is **opened**.

Valid object where most recent event status is opened -

```
{
    "subject" : "Hello there",
    "events" : [
        {
            "status" : "opened",
            "date" : 2020-01-02 17:35:31.229Z 
        },
        {
            "status" : "clicked",
            "date" : 2020-01-01 17:35:31.229Z 
        },
   ]
}
```

Invalid object where status isn't most recent

```
{
    "subject" : "Hello there",
    "events" : [
        {
            "status" : "opened",
            "date" : 2020-01-01 17:35:31.229Z 
        },
        {
            "status" : "clicked",
            "date" : 2020-01-02 17:35:31.229Z 
        },
   ]
}
```

At the moment I have the query that can check if any event has the status opened, but I'm unsure how to query only the top 1 and sorted by the dates of a nested query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var filter = Builders<Notification>.Filter.Empty;

filter &= Builders<Notification>.Filter.Regex("events.event", new BsonRegularExpression(searchString, "i"));

var results = await collection.FindSync(filter, findOptions).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 7):

In order to get only the latest event you can use `$reduce` to iterate over the events and compare each one to the temporarily latest:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      latestEvent: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$events",
          initialValue: {status: null, date: 0},
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $gt: [{$toDate: "$$this.date"}, {$toDate: "$$this.value"}]
                  },
                  "$$this",
                  "$$value"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Aj6QbtZ-hWM)

Comment: Hi there, wonderful answer. Unfortunately I'm doing this on c# and not quite sure how to translate this to c# mongo driver

Comment: You can use AppendStage methods to declare any query you need. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66442180/mongodb-fluent-aggregate-conditional-stages

Comment: db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("coll").Aggregate<BsonDocument>(new EmptyPipelineDefinition<BsonDocument>().AppendStage<BsonDocument, BsonDocument, BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse("{ $addFields : { .. } }")));

Comment: This is more of a mongo answer which works using the mongo driver because you can construct BsonDocument queries pretty handily, however coupled with C#, the user is not necessarily familiar with MongoDb Querying and wants to do the strongly typed EF-like way to not have to know the DB backend, like the comment suggests

Answer (score 0):

for multiple documents, the result return only correct documents
[example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/odUWX_zpLJU)

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        lastevent: {
            $filter: {
                input: '$events',
                as: 'element',
                cond: {$eq: ['$$element.date',{$max: '$events.date'}]}
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        'lastevent.status': 'opened'
    }
}])
```

Comment: This is more of a mongo answer which works using the mongo driver because you can construct BsonDocument queries pretty handily, however coupled with C#, the user is not necessarily familiar with MongoDb Querying and wants to do the strongly typed EF-like way to not have to know the DB backend, if using a cloud provider you also might not want to have indexes to support this complicated projection even if when given it will possibly be more efficient (depending on pct of things excluded)

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of not using an axe for everything, even if it is a good one :)

So i take it the events being disorderly is a rare thing, so we don't need to spend a lot of resources to weed out those up front as they will be few.

So my take is to get all the opened ones and use simple .net iteration to remove the few that may be, leaving a nice and orderly and easily maintainable method.

```
public List<Notification> GetValidSubjectStatusList(IMongoCollection<Notification> mongoCollection){
    
    var builder = Builders<Notification>.Filter;
    var filter = builder.Eq(x => x.Events.FirstOrDefault().Status, "opened");
    var listOf = mongoCollection.Find(filter).ToList();
    var reducedList = new List<Notification>();
    foreach(var hit in listOf){
        if(hit.Events.Any() 
                        && hit.Events.First()
                                        .Date.Equals(hit.Events
                                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                                            .FirstOrDefault()
                                        ))
            {
                reducedList.Add(hit);
            }
    }
    return reducedList;
}
```